# What is "Creed" in the Matoi Universe?

Tags: matoi-the-sacred-slayer

It stuck me that I have no idea what is supposed to be "Creed" in the Matoi Anime.

The girls like Clarus Tonitrus and Flors are "Anti-Creed". So they are something that opposes "Creed". From this one could assume that the Nights are "Creed".

But the Night-vodoo-dude that maimed Flors is the "Creed Killer". Since he has a ton of bracelets, one could assume that he killed lots of girls, and from that infer that "Creed" are the divine union girls of Fatima.

But then both definitions do not converge. Each one point to the different faction.

What is "Creed" supposed to mean?